# Performance of variable argument methods in Java

Tags: java, performance

I have this question about the performance of a method in Java with a variable number of parameters.

Say I have the following 2 alternatives:

```
public static final boolean isIn(int i, int v1, int v2) {
    return (v1 == i) || (v2 == i);
}

public static final boolean isIn(int i, int... values) {
    for (int v : values) {
        if (i == v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now the main problem comes when I have versions of the first method that go up to 20, 30 or even 50 parameters. Now that just hurts the eyes. Ok, this is legacy code and I'd like to replace all of it with the only one variable arguments method.

Any idea what the impact on performance would be? Any chance the compiler does some optimization for the second method so that it resembles the first form more or less?

**EDIT:** Ok, maybe I was not clear enough. I don't have performance problems with the methods with 50 arguments. It's just about readability as Peter Lawrey said. 
I was wondering about **performance problems if I switch to the new method with variable number of arguments**.
**In other words: what would be the best way to do it** if you care about performance? Methods with 50 arguments or the only one method with variable arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question, and turned to experimentation.

```
public class ArgTest {

  int summation(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {
    return a + b + c + d + e + f;
  }

  int summationVArgs(int... args) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int arg : args) {
      sum += arg;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  final static public int META_ITERATIONS = 200;
  final static public int ITERATIONS = 1000000;

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    final ArgTest at = new ArgTest();
    for (int loop = 0; loop < META_ITERATIONS; loop++) {
      int sum = 0;
      final long fixedStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        sum += at.summation(2312, 45569, -9816, 19122, 4991, 901776);
      }
      final long fixedEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
      final long vargStart = fixedEnd;
      for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
        sum += at.summationVArgs(2312, 45569, -9816, 19122, 4991, 901776);
      }
      final long vargEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.printf("%03d:%d Fixed-Args: %d ms\n", loop+1, ITERATIONS, fixedEnd - fixedStart);
      System.out.printf("%03d:%d Vargs-Args: %d ms\n", loop+1, ITERATIONS, vargEnd - vargStart);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

}
```

If you run this code on a modern JVM (here 1.8.0_20), you will see that the variable number of arguments cause overhead in performance and possible in memory consumption as well.

I'll only post the first 25 runs:

```
001:1000000 Fixed-Args: 16 ms
001:1000000 Vargs-Args: 45 ms
002:1000000 Fixed-Args: 13 ms
002:1000000 Vargs-Args: 32 ms
003:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
003:1000000 Vargs-Args: 27 ms
004:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
004:1000000 Vargs-Args: 22 ms
005:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
005:1000000 Vargs-Args: 38 ms
006:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
006:1000000 Vargs-Args: 11 ms
007:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
007:1000000 Vargs-Args: 17 ms
008:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
008:1000000 Vargs-Args: 40 ms
009:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
009:1000000 Vargs-Args: 89 ms
010:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
010:1000000 Vargs-Args: 21 ms
011:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
011:1000000 Vargs-Args: 16 ms
012:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
012:1000000 Vargs-Args: 26 ms
013:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
013:1000000 Vargs-Args: 7 ms
014:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
014:1000000 Vargs-Args: 7 ms
015:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
015:1000000 Vargs-Args: 6 ms
016:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
016:1000000 Vargs-Args: 141 ms
017:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
017:1000000 Vargs-Args: 139 ms
018:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
018:1000000 Vargs-Args: 106 ms
019:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
019:1000000 Vargs-Args: 70 ms
020:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
020:1000000 Vargs-Args: 6 ms
021:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
021:1000000 Vargs-Args: 5 ms
022:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
022:1000000 Vargs-Args: 6 ms
023:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
023:1000000 Vargs-Args: 12 ms
024:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
024:1000000 Vargs-Args: 37 ms
025:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
025:1000000 Vargs-Args: 12 ms
...
```

Even at the best of times, the Vargs-Args never dropped to 0ms.

Comment: As commented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541857/4026792, the difference is probably due to using for loops vs summing directly.

Answer (score 5):

to @Canonical Chris

I don't think problem at your test come from variable argument. The function sumationVArgs take more time to complete because of `for loop`.

I created this function and added to the benchmark

```
int summationVArgs2(int... args) {
        return args[0] + args[1] + args[2] + args[3] + args[4] + args[5];
    }
```

and this is what I see:

```
028:1000000 Fixed-Args: 0 ms
028:1000000 Vargs-Args: 12 ms
028:1000000 Vargs2-Args2: 0 ms
```

The `for loop` in function "summationVArgs" is compiled to more operations  than add function. It contains `add operation` to increase iterator, `check operation` to check condition and `branch operation` to loop and exit loop, and all of them execute once for each loop except branch opration to exit loop.

Sorry for my bad English. I hop you can understand my English :)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does next to no optimisation. The JVM can optimise code but the two methods won't perform anything like each other. If you have lines of code like `isIn(i, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 /* plus 40 more */)` you have more than performance issues to worry about IMHO. I would worry about readability first.

If you are worried about performance pass the arguments as a `int[]` which is reused.

BTW The most efficient way to look up a large set of int values is to use a Set like TIntHashSet

Answer (score 2):

Come back when you have profiler output that says this is a problem. Until then, it's premature optimization.

Comment: Well the problem with the methods with high number of arguments is not performance, maybe you misinterpreted my question. The problem is that I find it quite silly to have 50 methods that do the same thing.

Comment: I agree that it would be silly to have 50 methods.  This is what varargs is good at replacing.

Comment: @Deelazee: I understood you perfectly well. You're worrying about the performance of vararg methods without any evidence that says there is a problem. Asking this question rather than just using varargs is premature optimization, i.e. a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

It will be the same as if you declared

```
 isIn(int i, int[] values) {
```

However there will be some some small overhead in packaging the variables up when calling your method

Answer (score 1):

Heard about the two optimisation rules:

- Don't optimize
- (For experts only!) Don't optimize yet

In other words this is nothing you should care about from the performance point of view.