# Can passing an object to a method increase performance over sending individual parameters

Tags: java, object, optimization, parameters

I am assigned to a job of optimizing performance of an Application.

Often it is needed to pass  16-25 parameters to the constructor, and setting them there.
I want to create a class &  object for this and set these values to the object and then pass.
It will be good to read. But will it do any good to my task (i.e performance optimization)?

Comment: Passing that many parameters to a constructor is a code smell anyway irrespective of performance. With that many parameters, you are very likely to make an error (e.g. reversing two parameters of the same type).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727336/performance-of-variable-argument-methods-in-java, that should help you.

Comment: I would suggest profiling various aspects of your application to identify where the bottle necks actually are before trying to optimise. For example, anything involving network access, poorly written database queries, etc.

Comment: Passing object does not mean it will travel from one location to other. It is just memory reference and I don't think it impact performance.

Comment: @Andy you would be just as likely to get constructor parameters reversed when creating the parameter object - it's the same problem just moved one level out. To clarify the parameter meanings, a builder is in order, but that's going to reduce performance, which seems to be the thrust of the question.

Comment: Would there be there any reuse of the parameter object, or would it be created strictly for passing a bunch of primitive parameters?

Comment: @Bohemian of course this is possible. However, if you have parameter objects with narrow purposes, you are less likely to accidentally confuse unrelated parameters.

Comment: Readability concerns aside, have you profiled the application? My gut feeling is you are on the wrong side of the 80/20 rule of optimization: 80% of the potential improvements are in 20% of the code, and vice versa.

Comment: @Snowman : I didn't and I don't know what that means.

Comment: @Shashank you specifically mentioned "optimizing performance." Step one is to "measure performance" so you know what areas need to be improved. I have a strong feeling that if there are performance concerns, you would be better off finding some wildly inefficient algorithm somewhere that could be redesigned rather than messing around with the quantity of method parameters.

Answer (score 15):

It might improve the performance slightly, but the main benefit would be increasing the readability of your code. A constructor with 16-25 parameters is not readable, and very hard to use.

Of course, you should only introduce new classes that make sense (i.e. the parameters are related to each other). There's no point is shoving 15-26 unrelated parameters to one class just for the sake of passing them to a constructor.

Comment: Why do you think it would improve performance? Aren't you just creating an extra object?

Comment: @Keppil you might be able to create that object once and use in many places.

Comment: @Keppil Well, copying one reference instead of 15-26 in each call to the constructor can make a small difference. Then again, instantiating the new object would also take time. That's why I wrote "it might". If you are creating that new instance once and reusing it in many calls to the other constructor, it might make a small improvement.

Comment: Good point. I'm not claiming that there would be any negative impact on performance, I just wanted to hear your reasoning for any possible improvements.

Comment: @Eran Can you back up your statement that "it might improve the performance slightly"? Given that that is the one thing that the OP is asking about in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I wrote in a comment why it might, but since I ran no benchmarks, I can't be sure of that. However, since any such improvement is likely to be negligible, the main motivation to make the change should be readability and maintenance, not performance.

Comment: @Eran Ok I agree with that. The point about readability was already made by the OP himself though. But I like your second comment about not just lumping them all together.

Comment: A class for passing in parameters allows you to change to payload without changing the method signature without causing a breaking change. Arguably, if the parameters go into one method, they are related by definition.

Answer (score 14):

Performance differences deriving from this, if any, are very unlikely to be noticeable.

If your task is to solve performance problems, then your first job is to locate where the problems are.  You do that by profiling the application.  Have you done that and has it demonstrated that the problem is in the parameter passing ?

Answer (score 5):

It would be fairly unusual in modern software to have 25 loose variables on a calling function, and then pass these explicitly to a method or ctor.

More often than not, in an OO design, these variables would instead already be packaged into a class (or a few classes), grouped on their logical responsibilities.

And since `Java` passes objects by reference, passing a single object reference on the stack could have some performance benefit (fewer variables to push to the stack). However the real benefit would be code readability and maintenance.

It must however be noted that doing so would require that the class of the object being passed be shared between consumer and service - this may be an issue, depending on what the transfer class is modelling (e.g. is it a Data Transfer Object, a Business Entity, a View Model, an XML / JSON serialization object, etc?). If sharing type between caller and callee would violate your architecture, then you would typically map the 25 variables into another suitable canonical class (or classes, again observing SRP refactoring concerns) and pass this(these), instead. At this point, there will be no performance benefit, but the readability / maintainability benefit will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

As oops suggest to collaborate multiple properties into a single unit called class , which is represented by an object so it will improve performance and readiness of code